# Working on select checkbox on one click of particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on select all checkbox and I am new at this I found some solutions but its not working.
I want to select all check box of perticular div 
I have 2 divs and there is separate select all checkbox for each div.
My problem is when I select one select all checkbox whole checkboxes get selected of both divs instead of this checkboxes of that div should be get selected only. Here is my code:

```js
$('#selectall').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('input').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('input').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
$('#selectall').trigger('change');

$('#selectall2').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('input').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('input').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
$('#selectall2').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Select All
  <input id='selectall' type="checkbox"><br>1.

  <input type="checkbox">2.
  <input type="checkbox">3.
  <input type="checkbox">4.
  <input type="checkbox">5.
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div>Select All
  <input id='selectall2' type="checkbox"><br>1.

  <input type="checkbox">2.
  <input type="checkbox">3.
  <input type="checkbox">4.
  <input type="checkbox">5.
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `'input'` selector is selecting *every* `input` in the document. Select only `input`s that are siblings of the clicked element instead, with the `siblings()` method:

```js
$('#selectall').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(this).siblings().prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $(this).siblings().prop('checked', false);
  }
});
$('#selectall').trigger('change');

$('#selectall2').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(this).siblings().prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $(this).siblings().prop('checked', false);
  }
});
$('#selectall2').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Select All
  <input id='selectall' type="checkbox"><br>1.

  <input type="checkbox">2.
  <input type="checkbox">3.
  <input type="checkbox">4.
  <input type="checkbox">5.
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div>Select All
  <input id='selectall2' type="checkbox"><br>1.

  <input type="checkbox">2.
  <input type="checkbox">3.
  <input type="checkbox">4.
  <input type="checkbox">5.
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

But it would be more elegant to give your select-all checkboxes classes instead of IDs, and then you can select them both at once:

```js
$('.selectall').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(this).siblings().prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $(this).siblings().prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Select All
  <input class='selectall' type="checkbox"><br>1.

  <input type="checkbox">2.
  <input type="checkbox">3.
  <input type="checkbox">4.
  <input type="checkbox">5.
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div>Select All
  <input class='selectall' type="checkbox"><br>1.

  <input type="checkbox">2.
  <input type="checkbox">3.
  <input type="checkbox">4.
  <input type="checkbox">5.
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Comment: No need to change the HTML. See my answer :)

Comment: @jonathanharry When an answer solves your problem, consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Simplest.
No change to HTML and can handle a reload

```js
$('[id^=selectall]').change(function() {  // id begins with selectall
  var chk = $(this).prop('checked');      // is it checked?
  $(this).siblings().prop('checked',chk); // set all its siblings
}).change(); // trigger now in case of reload
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Select All
  <input id='selectall' type="checkbox"><br>1.

  <input type="checkbox">2.
  <input type="checkbox">3.
  <input type="checkbox">4.
  <input type="checkbox">5.
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div>Select All
  <input id='selectall2' type="checkbox" checked><br>1.

  <input type="checkbox">2.
  <input type="checkbox">3.
  <input type="checkbox">4.
  <input type="checkbox">5.
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```